# Application displaying mobile styles for certain features in local environment

Tags: angular, responsive-design, environment-variables, localhost, .env

In my local environment, the application is showing mobile styles for specific features, while the same code works correctly in the DEV, STG, and PROD environments. This issue is causing inconsistency and incorrect display of styles in the local environment. We are using media queries for responsive design across different devices. Also we used `navigator.userAgent` at some places to disply few blocks of code based on the device.

For example header in home page using mobile styles only in local environment whereas the same code works well in other environments.

I looked into .env file/webpack configuration bewteen the environments, but no luck.

Any inputs on how I can fix/debug this issue would be helpful?